# ¿Es posible acceder o representar la gráfica de actividad mostrada en twitter anlytics con la actividad de los últimos 28 días vía API?

Tags: twitter-api

Desde twitter analytics, en la sección "Tweets", se puede visualizar un gráfico de barras con la actividad de los últimos 28 días.
¿Es posible acceder a ese gráfico via API o insertarlo en una web mediante un código de inserción (tipo embebido)?

[image: Actividad de Tweets]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A día de hoy **no existe una API oficial para Twitter Analytics** y, aunque parece que bastante gente la está pidiendo, no parece que vaya a crearse a corto plazo ([fuente en inglés](https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-analytics-api/27296)). En ese mismo enlace puedes ver que sí existe una URL desde donde puedes obtener la información que buscas:

https://analytics.twitter.com/user/[usuario]/home/summary.json

pero **su uso no es recomendado porque no es oficial y estarías violando el acuerdo de uso** para desarrolladores (además de que podría dejar de funcionar en cualquier momento sin aviso previo).

Ahora, eso no quiere decir que no se pueda hacer. No hay un modo para obtener directamente la imagen, pero sí que existen métodos para obtener los datos necesarios para generar una gráfica similar. Al menos se me ocurren dos, aunque ambos funcionarían de manera similar, sólo diferirían en cómo se obtiene la información:

**Método 1: descargando el .csv desde Twitter Analytics**

La idea sería "simple": procesar el fichero .csv que se proporciona en Twitter Analytics para obtener la información necesaria para dibujar la gráfica. El algoritmo a seguir sería algo como esto:

1. Navega al sitio de [Twitter Analytics](https://analytics.twitter.com/) y ve a la pestaña de Tweets.
2. Descarga el fichero .csv (pulsando en el botón de exportar datos).
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Ahora que tienes el fichero con valores separados por coma (CSV), ponla en un sitio donde lo puede leer tu página web.
4. Procesa el CSV para transformarlo en datos que se puedan usar fácilmente en la web (p.e.: JSON). Los campos que te interesan son:

   - `time`: la fecha y hora a la que se publicó el tweet.
   - `impressions`: el número de veces que se mostró el tweet.
   - `engagements`: el número de veces que un usuario interactuó con el tweet.
5. Pasa los datos a una biblioteca que te genere automáticamente la gráfica. Ejemplos de bibliotecas que puedes usar:

   - [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/)
   - [Highcharts.js](http://www.highcharts.com/)
   - [D3.js](https://d3js.org/)

Ventajas de este método:

- Obtienes toda la información que necesitas de manera segura.
- Puedes seleccionar rangos de fechas diferentes a 28 días.

Inconvenientes de este método:

- La descarga del `.csv` se tiene que hacer de manera manual porque [no existe un método para hacerlo de manera directa](https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-analytics-api/27296/6#post_10) (aunque puede que alguien con más experiencia que yo se le ocurra alguna posibilidad).
- Sólo mostrará información de un usuario en particular (el que tenga acceso a descargar el csv).

---

**Método 2: usando la API de Twitter**

Aunque no haya API para Twitter Analytics, sí que puedes usar la [API general de Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation) para obtener los tweets de un usuario concreto. En particular necesitarías la [API pública que devuelve los tweets del timeline del usuario](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline).

El algoritmo en este caso sería:

1. Mientras no hayas alcanzado el límite de tweets (3.200) y no hayas alcanzado la fecha límite (28 días en el pasado):

   1. Haz una llamada a `statuses/user_timeline`
   2. Procesa el JSON para quedarte sólo con la información que te interesa (NOTA- puede que necesites hacer llamadas adicionales para obtener más información sobre cada tweet):

      - `created_at`: la fecha y hora a la que se publicó el tweet.
      - `retweet_count`: el número de retweets del post.
      - `favorite_count`: el número de veces que el tweet se ha hecho favorito.
   3. Vuelve al paso 1.1.
2. Ahora que tienes la información, este paso sería similar al paso 5 del método anterior: pasa los datos a una biblioteca que te genere automáticamente la gráfica. Ejemplos de bibliotecas que puedes usar:

   - [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/)
   - [Highcharts.js](http://www.highcharts.com/)
   - [D3.js](https://d3js.org/)

Ventajas de este método:

- Se puede hacer de manera automática.
- Podrías obtener datos y generar gráficas para diferentes cuentas de Twitter.

Inconvenientes de este método:

- Hay un límite tanto de llamadas como de número de tweets que puedes descargar. Aunque lo primero no debería ser un problema (reusando datos previamente descargados), lo segundo sí podría serlo (al menos al principio): la API devolverá como máximo los últimos 3.200 tweets del usuario, si escribió más de 3.200 en los últimos 28 días, la gráfica no tendría datos para los primeros días. Aunque si guardas la información en una base de datos, esto tampoco debería ser un problema pasado el tiempo.
- No se puede obtener toda la información que se muestra en Twitter Analytics (por ejemplo, el número de impresiones)

Comment: Gran respuesta!! Gracias. El método 2 es similar a lo que tenía pensado hacer. Esperaba que si hubiera una API para Twitter Analytics.

Comment: Parece que el número de impresiones sólo es accesible vía API por medio de GNIP [REST API support for Impressions data?](https://twittercommunity.com/t/rest-api-support-for-impressions-data/13169/22)

Answer (score 0):

### WebScraping is the solution

Hola, como aporte a esta consulta, pensaste en hacer WebScraping ? Es una manera excelente de acceder a informacion sin utilizar API's, ni rateLimit , ni nada parecido. Un lenguaje que humildemente te recomendaria es Python con BeautifulSoup, bastante comodo y efectivos, como BackEnd .. guardar esa informacion en el formato que mas te guste o con el que mejor te sientas y 'parsearlo' con javascript para mostrarlo en el navegador, o cualquier otro metodo para escritorio.
Yo he hecho algunas cosas y es realmente efectivo, Internet es una gigantesca BD abierta !.
Espero te sirva este concepto !
Saludos cordiales !

- [Python](https://www.python.org/)
- [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)
- [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)
- [Una referencia interesante](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/)